# How to create a custom Bevy bundle from a bundle with custom material

Tags: rust, bundle, bevy

My goal is to create a custom Bevy bundle that extends a built-in one so that I can reuse it. I start with `MaterialMesh2DBundle` which I've modified to have a custom fragment shader by changing the `material` field to one that is derived from `Material2d` and spawn it

```
commands.spawn(MaterialMesh2dBundle {
    mesh: meshes.add(Mesh::from(shape::Quad::default())).into(),
    transform: Transform::default().with_scale(Vec3::splat(640.)),
    material: materials.add(CustomMaterial {}),
    ..default()
});
...

// Custom material
#[derive(Asset, TypePath, AsBindGroup, Debug, Clone)]
struct CustomMaterial {}

impl Material2d for CustomMaterial {
    fn fragment_shader() -> ShaderRef {
        "shaders/custom_frag.wgsl".into()
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to put this all into a bundle to reuse in my code. Something like:

```
#[derive(Bundle)]
struct CustomBundle {
    sprite: MaterialMesh2dBundle<CustomMaterial>,
}

impl Default for CustomBundle {
    fn default() -> Self {
        // default implementation here
    }
}
```

So that eventually I can just use the custom bundle:

```
commands.spawn(CustomBundle {
    ..default()
});
```